# How do I fix color sliders in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to get color sliders to work on Tkinter. This should be easy but I think my math is off. They only control the red color not green or blue. I used repl.it to write the code. I think the issue lies in the color_changed section where it formats the slider variables but I could be wrong.

Here's my code

```
import tkinter 

# Create root window 

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.wm_title('Color Explorer')


# Create IntVar and initialize them to 127
red_intvar = tkinter.IntVar() 
red_intvar.set(127) 

green_intvar = tkinter.IntVar() 
green_intvar.set(127) 

blue_intvar = tkinter.IntVar() 
blue_intvar.set(127) 

# Create global variables for radius and center
r = 100
x = 150 
y = 150


# Event handler for slider
def color_changed(new_intval):
    canvas.itemconfig(circle_item, fill='#' + hexstring(red_intvar) \
    + '00' + '00')
    editor.insert(tkinter.END, '#' + \
    hexstring(red_intvar) + hexstring(green_intvar) + hexstring(blue_intvar))
    editor.see(tkinter.END) 

# Instantiate and place sliders
red_slider = tkinter.Scale(root, from_=0, to=255, variable=red_intvar, 
orient=tkinter.HORIZONTAL, label='Red', command=color_changed)
red_slider.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tkinter.E)

green_slider = tkinter.Scale(root, from_=0, to=255, variable=green_intvar, 
orient=tkinter.HORIZONTAL, label='Green', command=color_changed)
green_slider.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tkinter.E)

blue_slider = tkinter.Scale(root, from_=0, to=255, variable=blue_intvar, 
orient=tkinter.HORIZONTAL, label='Blue', command=color_changed)
blue_slider.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=tkinter.E)

# Create and place directions for the user
text = tkinter.Label(root
###############################################
# Model, text='Drag slider \nto adjust\ncircle.')
text.grid(row=0, column =0)

# Create and place a canvas
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400, background='#FFFFFF')
canvas.grid(row=0, rowspan=3, column=1)

circle_item = canvas.create_oval(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, 
outline = '#000000', fill='#7F7F7F') 
editor = tkinter.Text(root, width=10)
editor.grid(column=2, row=0, rowspan=3)

def hexstring(slider_intvar):
    slider_int = slider_intvar.get()
    slider_hex = hex(slider_int)

    slider_hex_digits = slider_hex[2:] 
    if len(slider_hex_digits)==1:
      slider_hex_digits = '0' + slider_hex_digits 
    return slider_hex_digits

#########################################################
# Event Loop

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Consider accepting [answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 0):

The following line inside `color_changed()`:

```
canvas.itemconfig(circle_item, fill='#' + hexstring(red_intvar) \
    + '00' + '00')
```

should be:

```
canvas.itemconfig(circle_item, fill='#' + hexstring(red_intvar) \
    + hexstring(green_intvar) + hexstring(blue_intvar)
```

Since you used the same color string in `canvas.itemconfig(...)` and `editor.insert(...)`, suggest to change `color_changed()` as below:

```
def color_changed(new_intval):
    color = "#"+hexstring(red_intvar)+hexstring(green_intvar)+hexstring(blue_intvar)
    canvas.itemconfig(circle_item, fill=color)
    editor.insert(tkinter.END, color+"\n")
    editor.see(tkinter.END)
```